# Is there a way to preserve data during disk migration on Softlayer?

Tags: disk, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have lots of VMs with system and portable local disks. I want to migrate them to SAN disks for system and portable disks through SL API. I did some experiment from SL portal, seems there has to migrate the system disk to SAN first, and open a SL support ticket to delete the local portable disk, then order a SAN portable disk after system disk migration is completed. So in this process, the data in local disk can't be automatically copied to the SAN disk, users have to figure out a way to copy data manually by themselves? I am wondering if there is safe/better way to help do data migration during disk migration? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there is no way to preserve data during disk migration.  The user needs to preserve and restore the data manually.

Comment: the anwer is that is not possible to do what he want to do :S